# Как сделать чтобы бот телеграм писал жирным шрифтом?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы телеграм бот писал жирным шрифтом ?
Например, как сделать чтобы BSUT Helper v0.1 Alpha бот написал жирным, а Дата выхода, курсивом ?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == 'О проекте  ':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'BSUT Helper v0.1 Alpha.\nПоследнее обновление: 18.11.2020\nДата выхода: 18.11.2020\nРазработчик @mikitos59', reply_markup=keyboard2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telegram поддерживает два формата разметки: HTML и Markdown.

пример с использованием Markdown.

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '*BSUT Helper v0.1 Alpha.\nПоследнее обновление: 18.11.2020\nДата выхода: 18.11.2020\nРазработчик @mikitos59*', reply_markup=keyboard2,parse_mode="Markdown")
```

между `*текст*` тест будет полужирным а между `_текст_` курсив.

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```py
bot = (TOKEN , parse_mode='HTML'
def command_start(message: Message)
   await message.anserv('Привет <b>(Текст)</b>
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо просто добавить атрибут parse_mode="html" и добавить теги html:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == 'О проекте  ':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>BSUT Helper v0.1 Alpha.\nПоследнее 
обновление: 18.11.2020\nДата выхода: 18.11.2020\nРазработчик @mikitos59</b>', 
reply_markup=keyboard2, parse_mode="html")
```